# Why target action in UITableViewCell gets lost?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to create a custom UITableViewCell with a UISwitch and without using a storyboard/.xib file.
The problem is that the action I set on the UISwitch seems to be lost because I can't trigger the selector action on switch tapped. Whereas the addTarget is set after the cell init. Also a tap on the switch does not toggle the state (no problem using a XIB file so the issue should not come from the UITableViewController)

```
class UISwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let switchUI : UISwitch = {
    let switchUI = UISwitch()
    return switchUI
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.selectionStyle = .none
    addSubview(switchUI)
    switchUI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    switchUI.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    switchUI.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    switchUI.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch){
    print("switch changed")
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoder init not implemented")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not about the target being deallocated or something similar.
The issue was caused by the cell default textLabel (below set with yellow background) that overlapped the UISwitch, preventing from touch interactions. So the solution was to hide that default label and create my own one with trailing constraint equals to the UISwitch leadingAnchor.

[image]

Comment: Also, the switch should be inside `contentView`, otherwise bad things will happen sooner or later.

Comment: Don't ask questions in your solutions. We don't want to start discussions on this site

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow the selection of UITableView and UITableviewCell

`tableView.allowsSelection = true`

`cell.selectionStyle = .default`

Comment: The selectionStyle is only a styling property with no impact on interactions. And allowsSelection is set to true by default

Comment: I asked selection style to confirm is there any other view who is overlapping with cell's content view. This is exactly the same case as you mentioned in your answer. 

I asked to set allow selection true, because sometimes it is set to false by mistake/other developer.